# jsp missing a Jar, unable to run from Tomcat but Eclipse works

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a jsp file that calls another java file from within the `<Body>` of the page, however I cannot seem to find a way for the jsp to reference this jar file from within the Tomcat container itself.  If I import the project into Eclipse via .war file, I can move the jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder and it compiles fine, however if I do the same via Tomcat itself, it doesn't seem to find the jars.

Comment: Try copying your jar file under TOMCAT_HOME/lib and then starting the tomcat server. Or, modify the class loader path (in conf/catalina.properties)

Comment: @nickspol that's terrible advice. A library needed by a webapp should be in the webapp, not in the global server classpath.